# How do I match all for controllers in a namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have some controllers under the namespace 'sandbox'.

```
/sandbox/misc/index
/sandbox/my_test/show_variables
...
```

I don't want to modify routes.rb every time I add controllers and actions in the sandbox namespace.

```
match ':controller/:action', via: :all
```

This will work but not just for sandbox but for everything.
How can I constrain it only for sandbox?

Thanks.

Sam

Comment: Are you generating the URLs like `sandbox/misc/index`? If you are, I think you can do `match "sandbox/:controler/:action"`

Comment: @gasc: It gives an error "The action 'index' could not be found for MiscController".

Comment: I'm sorry, the controller is called `IndexController`?

Comment: @gasc: No. MiscController. So sandbox is the namespace, misc is the controller and index is the action.

Comment: And of course, you have index action defined in your `MiscController` , do you?

Comment: @gasc: Of course. Even if it's not defined, I don't think it would cause the routing error. Some actions work without method definition and the view file would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the best solution. This works as I wish.

match ":controller/:action", via: :all, constraints: -> req {
  req.original_fullpath =~ /^\/sandbox\//
}

This was tested on Rails 4.2. It turned out that it's not working with Rails 5.2.